# Save object to memcached with Finagle memcached client

Tags: serialization, memcached, netty, finagle

com / twitter / finagle / memcached / Client   extends BaseClient[ChannelBuffer]

so the set is defined as

set(key: String, flags: Int, expiry: Time, value: ChannelBuffer): Future[Unit]

My question is how can I convert my java Object to a netty ChannelBuffer or I have some other way to set object other than String?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used thrift to do the serialization. It's just my case, because I have heavily used thrift.

The disadvantage of thrift serialization: you had to define the struct of the object in the IDL.

The advantage is: simple

```
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer();
byte[] bytes = serializer.serialize(obj);
ChannelBuffer buffer = ChannelBufferUtils.bytesToChannelBuffer(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you!
You can use whatever serialization library you want, there is plenty of alternatives.
memcached only consider it as a array of bytes.